# Configure log levels from SMTPAppender

Tags: logging, log4j2

How to only include warning and higher level events in an smtp appender?

> The SMTPAppender keeps only the last BufferSize logging events in its cyclic buffer. This keeps memory requirements at a reasonable level while still delivering useful application context. All events in the buffer are included in the email. The buffer will contain the most recent events of level **TRACE** to **WARN** preceding the event that triggered the email.
>
> The default behavior is to trigger sending an email whenever an **ERROR** or higher severity event is logged and to format it as HTML. The circumstances on when the email is sent can be controlled by setting one or more filters on the Appender.
>   [Log4j2 SMTPAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SMTPAppender)

According to this [comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-488?focusedCommentId=13865715&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-13865715) the **email send** event is bound to **threshold filter**. Configuring the threshold filter changes the level of events which trigger sending an email but does not influence what will be saved in the buffer.

Changing the logger level itself isn't feasible since events shall be handled by other appenders as well.

```
<Appender>
    ....
    <SMTP name="Mail" subject="Error Log"
        to="${mailTo}" smtpHost="smtp.googlemail.com"
        smtpProtocol="smtps" smtpPort="465" bufferSize="512"
        smtpUsername="${smtpUsername}"
        smtpPassword="${smtpPassword}">
        <ThresholdFilter level="WARN" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
    </SMTP>
    <Async name="AsyncMail">
        <AppenderRef ref="Mail" />
    </Async>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.github.kilianB" level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
        <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
        <AppenderRef ref="AsyncMail" />
    </Logger>
</Loggers>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the level on the appender? E.g. `<AppenderRef ref="AsyncMail" level="warn"/>` ? If that doesn't work then it seems likely the level of the events included in the buffer is not configurable. You would probably have to write a custom appender to do what you want.